# How to show this function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, integration

How do I show that
$$\int_{\Omega(t)} |\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(t)g_i(t)|^p$$
is measurable wrt $t \in [0,T]$, where $f_i(t)$ is continuous wrt $t \in [0,T]$ and $g_i(t)=\mathbf{1}_{B_i}(t)$  is measurable wrt $t \in [0,T]$ (the $B_i$ are dissjoint and measurable)?

Also $f_i(t) \in \Omega(t)$ for all $t$.

Note that domain of integration depends on $t$. Make any assumptions necessary.

Comment: Are $f,g$ also functions of $\omega\in\Omega(t)$? What's supposed to be under the absolute value, and what role does the sum play?

Comment: @Yes they're functions of $\omega.$ Sorry I edited the abs value. I guess the sum doesn't matter. I just icnluded it as that's what i have.

Comment: But then surely there are $f_n,g_n$ as well? Also, I'm still not clear on the function's domain, if you don't mind fleshing it out a little.

Comment: Yes you're right. I edited. Note the $g_n$ are constant wrt. $\Omega(t)$. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been clearer. I'm asking regarding the integration variable. Do we have, for all $n,t$, that $f_n(t):\Omega(t)\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous (in $\omega$, given some natural topology, say), or something else? How would you formulate what you're getting at?

Comment: No need to apologise, it's my fault for not being clear. (I am still not that sure tbh). For all $n,t$ $f_n(t)(\cdot):\Omega(t) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $t$, not in $\omega.$ So $t \mapsto f(t)$ is a continuous function. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10227/discussion-between-jonathan-y-and-aere)

Comment: @JonathanY. I'm afraid I have to leave soon but I will try to add more detail and join you in chat later on. Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: Is $\Omega(t) \subset \Omega$ for some measurable set $\Omega$, so that we are really looking at $\int_{\Omega} \chi_{\Omega_t} |\sum f_t g_t|^p d\mu$?

Comment: @B.Mackey No, but suppose that there is a smooth diffeomorphism between $F:\Omega(0)$ and $\Omega(t)$ for each $t$. The determinant of the derivative of $F$ is bounded away from 0 and is independent of $t$. So we can change the domain of integration to $\Gamma(0)$...